# Is there a web app that lets me read PDFs on a computer that does not have a PDF reader installed?

Tags: webapp-rec, pdf

I have in the past email PDF new letters to friends and them be told by them that they can’t read the PDF as there is not a PDF reader on the machine they are using and they don’t know how to install one, or their IT department will not allow a PDF read to be installed.

So how do I let them read a PDF newsletter?

I am looking for a web app that lets me upload a PDF, and then give me a web link I can email to people.   I want that web link to work even if the person does not have a PDF reader.   (It is **not** safe to assume they have flash etc)

Comment: Flush ? Do you mean flash ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are plenty of different ways of doing it and in addition to neo's answer, there is a very easy way of getting a [public link](https://www.dropbox.com/help/16) to any of your files using [Dropbox](http://dropbox.com) and afterwards using the link (`http://docs.google.com/viewer?url={url}`)

But, I think the fastest way is:

- Send the `PDF` file to your self using Gmail
- Click the `view` button next to the attachment

Comment: I like the ideal of just email the PDF to my self, then giving out the link, assume that the list lasts for long enough etc

Answer (score 4):

I think you can do all that with Google Docs. They have a PDF viewer and they also allow you to share docs by link.

Here's a bit more info on PDF viewing from an older blog post of theirs: http://googledocs.blogspot.com/2009/09/view-online-files-using-google-docs.html

[edit]

An even easier option could be ZohoViewer. They allow you to upload a document, get a link and even set an expiration date on it. Pretty slick really and very single focused to this sort of thing.  http://viewer.zoho.com/

Answer (score 0):

One possibility is to upload the pdf file to any webspace and then point to Google pdf viewer (which supports now even *.doc*) `http://docs.google.com/viewer?url={url}`.

You could also upload the files to Google Docs. There should be a public link to share.

Another service (which allows you even to upload the files there) is [scribd](http://www.scribd.com/), which doesn't seem to use flash anymore.

Answer (score 0):

Google Docs would certainly work. I can think of two other options that would certainly address your issue.

- [Scribd](http://www.scribd.com): Has a desktop uploader that allows bulk uploads
- [Docstoc](http://www.docstoc.com)

Both these allow you to embed your documents on other websites.

Answer (score -2):

There is no need to any online tool just drag and drop the pdf in chrome browser and you will be able to see this pdf